# computing prime factors using same code produces different results?

Tags: f#, primes, biginteger

I am basically trying to compute the factors of a BigInteger that are a prime, I have two simple factorization functions, they both look like they should produce the same result in the way I used them here down below but this is not the case here, can someone explain what is happening?

```
let lookupTable = new HashSet<int>(primes)

let isPrime x = lookupTable.Contains x

let factors (n:bigint) = 
    Seq.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0I) [1I..n]

let factors' (n:bigint) = 
    Seq.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0I) [1I..bigint(sqrt(float(n)))]


600851475143I
|> fun n -> bigint(sqrt(float(n)))
|> factors
|> Seq.map int
|> Seq.filter isPrime
|> Seq.max // produces 137

600851475143I
|> factors'
|> Seq.map int
|> Seq.filter isPrime
|> Seq.max // produces 6857 (the right answer)
```

Comment: The first program factorizes `sqrt(n)`, not `n`. I'm voting to close this question for "typographical error" reason.

Comment: I actaully said "they should produce the same result ***in the way I used them*** here down below" and I meant the piece of code after the function definitons

Comment: Your intent doesn't change the nature of the actual mistake; @bytebuster is totally correct in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions are not equivalent. In the first function, the list of candidates goes to `n`, and the filter function also uses `n` for remainder calculation. The second function, however, also uses `n` for remainder calculation, but the candidates list goes to `sqrt(n)` instead.

To make the second function equivalent, you need to reformulate it like this:

```
let factors' (n:bigint) = 
    let k = bigint(sqrt(float(n)))
    Seq.filter (fun x -> k % x = 0I) [1I..k]
```

**Update**, to clarify this somewhat:
In the above code, notice how `k` is used in two places: to produce the initial list of candidates and to calculate remainder within the filter function? This is precisely the change I made to your code: my code uses `k` in both places, but your code uses `k` in one place, but `n` in the other.

This is how your original function would look with `k`:

```
let factors' (n:bigint) = 
    let k = bigint(sqrt(float(n)))
    Seq.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0I) [1I..k]
```

Notice how it uses `k` in one place, but `n` in the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was not talking about the equivalence of functions. You see when I used the first function, (the one whose candidates goes to n) I passed the square root of 600851475143 and in the second (the one whose candidates goes to sqrt(n)) I passed just 600851475143

Comment: That's the point: in the first function, you use that `sqrt`-ed value for _both_ filter function and initial list, but in the second function, the `sqrt`-ed value is only used for initial list, but not for filter function. Functions are not identical, even if you control for the different arguments passed to them.